# UnknownHostException when accessing api.twitter.com

Tags: android, exception, twitter, httpclient

I'm trying to access this list of public twitts here,
from an android application through a HttpClient:

**http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json**

I keep getting an Exception when connecting:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: api.twitter.com
```

Why is this happening?
How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure you have the INTERNET permission added to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Feel so stupid.Before this I was developing for the iPhone, so I kinda forgot this kind of details...Thank you very much!

Comment: i have this permissin <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> still i am getting error